# Word for when set A is not a subset or superset of set B

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

I'm looking for a word to describe the relationship between two sets when set A is neither a subset nor superset of set B. Obviously if a technical term exists, great.

Otherwise, imagine someone has inquired whether set A is related to set B. They are only interested in the subset/superset relationship. I reply by saying that set A is (a subset/a superset/equal to/**_???**) set B. I'm fine with stripping articles, prepositions, etc off to get a single word.

Comment: This is really a math question.  If the two sets are not in a subset/superset relationship they may be *disjoint* (with no common elements), or they may have an *intersection* of some elements which are common between the two sets.

Comment: The sets are *incomparable*, but, to avoid any misunderstanding, you might have to say *incomparable with respect to inclusion*.

Comment: You might say the sets are *unrelated*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on a Math SE site, not here.

Comment: @tchrist Call off the CPVPV.  This is about an English word for a non-inclusional relationship between groups.

Comment: @Lawrence The sets could have a non-empty intersection

Comment: There are two more cases. `A` and `B` could be disjoint, or they may have a nonempty intersection, but without either containing all of the other. You need a term for {is disjoint with `or` is equal to `or` intersects with}. There isn't any, unless you define one.

Comment: What @JohnLawler and HotLicks said. The sets could be disjoint (they have an empty intersecttion) or they could have a non-empty intersection that is a proper subset of each of them. (A proper subset is a subset unequal to the set itself.)

Comment: @deadrat - As you can see, the folks here have given several mathematically incorrect answers.  Better to have the question somewhere where it will be evaluated by mathematicians.

Comment: @deadrat I should have added *in common parlance*, or said that *the sets are unrelated (or not related) by containment*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sets A and B do not share any element they are "*disjoint sets*"

If sets A and B share some elements (*their intersection isn't the empty set*), then they are "*intersecting sets*"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29#Intersecting_and_disjoint_sets

Answer (score 3):

With respect to the [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition) of set inclusion, the sets are *[incomparable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability)*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this might be a bit technical, but here's how you'd classify verbally each scenario:

If every element in A is contained in B (but not necessarily vice-versa), A is a *subset* of B. E.g.: A = {1,2,3} and B = {1,2,3,4,5}

If every element in B is contained within A (again not always vice-versa), A is a superset of B. E.g.: A = {9,8,7,6} and B = {7,6}.

If they are neither subsets nor supersets of each other, the following scenarios are possible:

If sets A and B share no elements, they are known as *disjoint* or *independent*. E.g. A = {1,2,3,4} and B = {7,8,9}.

If sets A and B share some elements (their intersection isn't the empty set) but one does not contain all elements from the other, I'm not aware of any special name for the sets -- they're basically just sets, and this is probably the most common scenario given two moderately sized sets of distributed data (hence no real need for a special name, I'm guessing).

Comment: "Independent" is ***NOT*** a synonym for "disjoint". Although.it is a common mistake of students in probability and statistics classes to confuse "disjoint" (aka "mutually exclusive") events with "independent" events, the two concepts are totally different, and mutually exclusive events are hardly ever independent.